# Can we change the google service account email address?

Tags: google-people-api

[Click here to see the image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fgFJ.png) We are using a service account as a manager to users/clients GMB listings, so when our user/client sees its listing users at the google my listings UI page, the user/client sees the email address of the service account, which is not readable for a client/user, so we want to show our company name or our email address.
so is it possible to change the format or service email address to our email address or any other way by which the user/client can see our email address instead of the service account email?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Answer:

*No, service account email addresses can't be changed at all. They are not a part of your domain and so can not be given a different email address. The best you can do is use [impersonation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/impersonating-service-accounts) to make the service account take actions on behalf of an account in your domain.*

Comment: we have to show the service account name to our user/client GMB users UI page instead of the service account email, is it possible?

Comment: @link2developer no it’s not possible, you would have to just display something else *instead* of the email, ignoring the email completely.

Comment: Google shows the account name for a personal account then why it can`t show the service account name there?

Comment: @link2developer A service account _isn't_ a user. It's a bot, it's just not designed in this way. It doesn't have a name, it has an email address which can't be changed as it's not in your domain. If you want it to have a proper name and/or email address then you will need to have it impersonate an account on your domain. If you're talking about the service account name, [that isn't what it's for](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts#updating) - the display name is just meant to be a friendly name to help you identify what the service account is used for.

Comment: @link2developer The display name under Google services is the name of the account - this is what is set up in the account itself at [accounts.google.com](https://accounts.google.com) as the preferred display name. You can't change this for a service account, as it's not a part of your domain.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for your time.